# How can i make a question "not on hold"

Tags: support

I have questions that got put on hold. For the first one, i have gotten an answer, however, i would not like it removed, as "put on hold" usually means it is on the "wanted to be removed" list. How can i make it not on hold? I have done further research and would like to add what i have found on there, so is there anyone who can make them "not on hold"?

Comment: `as "put on hold" usually means it is on the "wanted to be removed" list.` That's not what it means at all . Put on hold means we have some problems we'd like you to fix with the current question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered in our Help Centre on the page [What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).

Perhaps the best advice I can offer in a case like this is that you should review the site [tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and our [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [How do I ask a good question?](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ok thanks......

Comment: Worth also stressing that question that are put on hold should be revised to fix issues, not simply restated in a new question as OP has done.